# Associated primes of the tensor product of a module with itself

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring $A$. Are the associated primes of the tensor product $M\otimes_A M$ same as the associated primes of $M$ ?

Comment: I suggest you calculate this for $M$ a maximal ideal (say in polynomial ring in 2 variables).

Comment: Thanks, got it. If we take $A=k[X,Y]$ and $M:=(X,Y)$ then $M$ is a torsion-free module over $A$. Now $m:=X \otimes Y - Y \otimes X$ is a nonzero element of $M \otimes_A M$, but $XY$ annihilates $m$.